# What does "." means in regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

hello friends I am new to pattern matching in php.

I tried this code to find text between '@' and 'space'

```
<?php
    $pattern = "%@(.*?)\s%";
    $string = "this is @test string @match ";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $match);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($match);
    echo "</pre>";
    ?>
```

It works fine no errors...
My question is what does "." means in this 
I know other symbol's meaning like

```
% is terminaor
( start of substring
) end of substring
* 0 or more match
```

etc .. but didnt understand the use of "." here..
can any body explain it .and correct me if I am wrong anywhere else

Thanks in advance

Comment: `.` means any character

Comment: Here is the page in the PHP manual that answers all of your questions like this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: @Gene probable you are right but I tried searching it but didnt understood the way in the way I have done it right now :)

Comment: @new_developer I just typed "php regex dot" in Google and the first listing had the answer.  Google is a programmer's best friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` matches any character except for newline characters. In your case it will match anything between `@` and a space except for newline characters or it can just be `'@ '` since you have  `.*?` which means that it is optional for the wild card `.`. To have the `.` to check everything including newline, add `s` after your delimiter `%` eg: `...%s` [s (PCRE_DOTALL)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Answer (score 1):

The `.` matches anything other than a newline character, but only one character.

Comment: Does it match newlines by [default](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php#regexp.reference.meta)? =oP

Comment: nope, you need a special flag for that. Regex is a *line* tool by default

Comment: This isn't fully correct.  By default it does not match newline \n.

Answer (score 0):

`.` means it will match any character.

Comment: Does it match newlines by [default](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php#regexp.reference.meta)? =oP

Comment: In most flavors of regex, no. The `.` is really an alias for `[^\n]` on unix flavors of regex and `[^\r\n]` on Windows flavors.

Answer (score 0):

The `.` means any character. A wildcard, if you will. You will find it useful whenever you will want to match a pattern, preceeded/followed by *anything*, but you do not wish to trouble youself what that thing is.

In the above regex you are matching `@`, then any number of characters, until you get to whitespace. The period allows you not to care whether your pattern is `@[` or `@lorem76-ipsum`. It will be matched.